# Get php session data

Tags: php

I set a php session like such:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_auth'] = [
    "email" => $resultObj->email,
    "displayName" => $resultObj->displayName,
    "token" => $resultObj->token
];
```

I can't find anything in my searches that's helpful yet, but how can I reference this session data later to use the token for another request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a 2d array so you can access it as you'd normally do for array types.

Like

```php
echo $_SESSION['user_auth']["email"];
echo $_SESSION['user_auth']["displayName"];
echo $_SESSION['user_auth']["token"];
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured this was easy but I rarely code PHP.